I have created a Record trigger flow on Feed Item with condition whenever Commentcount changes it should perform some automation
I have created a record trigger flow on FeedItem with condition whenever Commentcount changes it should perform some automation. But when I add a comment in chatter post the count is changing for field CommentCount in developer console but the flow is not triggering. Please help me where i'm missing.

This question is similar to: What is the best workaround for the lack of the FeedItem/FeedComment trigger firing when you like a Chatter post?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can't create a record triggered flow on the FeedComment, but you can create a trigger for it. So instead of trying to detect whether CommentCount changed in the parent FeedItem record, you can set up your automation to run when the comment is created instead.
